# Loader with five column bars

Tags: html, css, css-animations, loader

I have created a loader in css with three bars, the code is as given below. The bars are based on `:before` and `:after`. But if I want a five bar loader how can I do that ?

```css
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
    background: black;
    -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    width: 1em;
    height: 4em;
}

.loader {
    color: black;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 8px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
    animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
}

.loader:before {
    left: -2em;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
    animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.loader:after {
    left: 2em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0;
        height: 4em;
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 -2em;
        height: 5em;
    }
}

@keyframes load1 {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0;
        height: 4em;
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 -2em;
        height: 5em;
    }
}

.loader-wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the CSS propriety `ntnchild`. Your HTML and CSS will be like:

```css
.loading-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: loading 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.loading-bar:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #3498db;
  animation-delay: 0;
}

.loading-bar:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #c0392b;
  animation-delay: 0.09s;
}

.loading-bar:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  animation-delay: .18s;
}

.loading-bar:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  animation-delay: .27s;
}

.loading-bar:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #000000;
  animation-delay: .36s;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  20% {
    transform: scale(1, 2.2);
  }

  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with only one element and gradient. You simply need to control the `background-size` to have the needed animation

You can find more ideas here: https://css-loaders.com/bars/

```css
.loader {
    width: 70px;
    height: 4em;
    margin: 10px auto;
    --g: no-repeat linear-gradient(black 0 0);
    background: var(--g),var(--g),var(--g),var(--g),var(--g);
    background-size:10px 100%;
    background-position:
      calc(0*100%/4),
      calc(1*100%/4),
      calc(2*100%/4),
      calc(3*100%/4),
      calc(4*100%/4);
    animation:load 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes load{
  0% {
     background-size:10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%;
  }
  15% {
     background-size:10px  50%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%;
  }
  30% {
     background-size:10px  80%,10px  50%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%;
  }
  45% {
     background-size:10px 100%,10px  80%,10px  50%,10px 100%,10px 100%;
  }
  60% {
     background-size:10px 100%,10px 100%,10px  80%,10px  50%,10px 100%;
  }
  75% {
     background-size:10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px  80%,10px  50%;
  }
  90% {
     background-size:10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px  80%;
  }
  100% {
     background-size:10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%,10px 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be use this killer way.

Please add new class like: `<div class="loader more">Loading...</div>`

And give this type of css:

```
.loader.more {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 95px;
    top: -10px;
}
.loader.more:after {
    left: 0;
}
```

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarification.

```css
  .loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
    background: black;
    -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    width: 1em;
    height: 4em;
}

.loader {
    color: black;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 8px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
    animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
}

.loader:before {
    left: -2em;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
    animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.loader:after {
    left: 2em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0;
        height: 4em;
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 -2em;
        height: 5em;
    }
}

@keyframes load1 {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0;
        height: 4em;
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 -2em;
        height: 5em;
    }
}

.loader-wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 56px;
}
.loader.more {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 95px;
    top: -10px;
}
.loader.more:after {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
  <div class="loader more">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried, i don't know this is a perfect solution.

```css
 .loader,
    .loader1,
    .loader:before,
    .loader1:before,
    .loader:after
     {
        background: black;
        -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
        animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
        width: 1em;
        height: 4em;
    }

    .loader,.loader1 {
        color: black;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: auto;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 8px;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
        animation-delay: -0.16s;
    }

    .loader:before,
    .loader1:before,
    .loader:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        content: '';
    }

    .loader:before, .loader1:before {
        left: -2em;
        -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
        animation-delay: -0.32s;
    }

    .loader:after {
        left: 2em;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes load1 {
        0%,
        80%,
        100% {
            box-shadow: 0 0;
            height: 4em;
        }
        40% {
            box-shadow: 0 -2em;
            height: 5em;
        }
    }

    @keyframes load1 {
        0%,
        80%,
        100% {
            box-shadow: 0 0;
            height: 4em;
        }
        40% {
            box-shadow: 0 -2em;
            height: 5em;
        }
    }

    .loader-wrapper {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 56px;
    }

     .loader
      {
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
        top: -45px;      
      }
```

```html
    <div class="loader-wrapper">
<div class="loader1">Loading...</div>
      <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have create loader using six bar. Using CSS you target specific div for delay in animation. As @João Pedro Schmitz suggest use `nth-child` CSS selector for selecting `div`. I give a space of `10px` after every `div` and start the animation of each div with delay `.12s`.

```css
/* This provide animated ajax loading image. */
.animatedBox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.animatedBox div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  animation: animatedBox 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1) infinite;
}

.animatedBox div:nth-child(1) {
  left: 20px;
  animation-delay: -0.60s;
}

.animatedBox div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 30px;
  animation-delay: -0.48s;
}

.animatedBox div:nth-child(3) {
  left: 40px;
  animation-delay: -0.36s;
}

.animatedBox div:nth-child(4) {
  left: 50px;
  animation-delay: -0.24s;
}

.animatedBox div:nth-child(5) {
  left: 60px;
  animation-delay: -0.12s;
}

.animatedBox div:nth-child(6) {
  left: 70px;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBox {
0% {
    top: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #333;
  }
  50%,100% {
    top: 0px;
    height: 10px;
 background: #333;
  } 
}
@keyframes animatedBox {
  0% {
    top: -11px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #333;
  }
  50%,100% {
    top: 0px;
    height: 25px;
 background: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animatedBox">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```